# format binary literals with std::cout

Tags: c++, console, output

Following code will write binary output of a number to the console like so:

> 00100000

```
#include <bitset>
using std::bitset;

#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    typedef const unsigned char byte;

    byte a = 0b00'000'000; // 0
    byte b = 0b00'000'001; // 1
    byte c = 0b00'000'010; // 2
    byte d = 0b00'000'100; // 4
    byte e = 0b00'001'000; // 8
    byte f = 0b00'010'000; // 16
    byte g = 0b00'100'000; // 32
    byte h = 0b01'000'000; // 64
    byte i = 0b10'000'000; // 128

    bitset<8> x = a | 1 << 5;

    cout << x << endl;
}
```

I would like the output to be this:

> 00'100'000

Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Comment: Maybe you can try to overload the `<<` operator for a `bitset`?

Comment: Why? in `operator<<` cout goes first. It's different from `bitset << value`.

Comment: I removed my comment. will try your suggestion

Comment: I'd suggest a named function instead of overloading. ADL is fun, until it doesn't work and you have to figure out why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one of solutions:

```
template<size_t I>
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const bitset<I>& b)
{
    int i;
    int check = b.size()-b.size()%3;

    for(i=b.size()-1; i >= check; --i)
        os << b[i];

    if(i>0)
        os << char(39);

    for(; i>=0; --i)
    {
        os << b[i];
        if(i%3 == 0 && i!=0)
            os << char(39);
    }
    return os;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream & stream, std::bitset<8> bitset)
{
    auto output_string = bitset.to_string();

    // here you format output_string as you want

    return stream << output_string;
}
```

Comment: Probably better to have `template <int N> std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream & stream, std::bitset<N> bitset)` so that it works for any `bitset` size.

Comment: @RedX anything you want, you may also templatize to char type and override `operator<<` for `basic_ostream` and so on, almost infinitely :-)